# Laravel 5.2 : How to save user's role in this example?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 and `Zizaco/entrust`,my question is:
In the following example,how to save user's role?

**register form ** which was added a `Role` item on the basis of the out-of-the-box form.

```
<form id="register" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST"  action="{{ url('/register') }}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 form-control-label">Role</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label class="c-input c-radio">
                <input id="role1" name="role" type="radio" value="1">
                <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                red team
            </label>
            <label class="c-input c-radio">
                <input id="role2" name="role" type="radio" value="2">
                <span class="c-indicator"></span>
                blue team
            </label>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 form-control-label">username</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('name'))
            <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </fieldset>


    <fieldset class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 form-control-label">email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
            @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 form-control-label">password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
        <label class="col-md-4 form-control-label">password confirmation</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
            <span class="help-block"><strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong></span>
            @endif
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**AuthController** out-of-the box.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I can make a RolesController and write a attachRole() function,Thus,I can manually attach a role to a user. like this:

```
public function attachRole()
{
    $user = User::where('name', '=', 'foo')->first();
    $user->roles()->attach(2);
    return "attachRole done";
}
```

Now, I want to save the role that was received from register form,but not  attach a role via attachRole() above.
How to modify the `create` function in AuthController?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the Authorization functionality in Laravel, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization.

Example code:

```
$gate->before(function ($user, $ability) {
    if ($user->isSuperAdmin()) {
        return true;
    }
});
```